# how to inject ng-bootstrap NgbDateParserFormatter in a utility class

Tags: angular, typescript, static

While reading/writing to datepicker, I have defined function to parse the year, month, day to date-format. I wanted to create a static class to use those function anywhere in my project as a Utility class. While doing so, I have a challenge with NgbDateParserFormatter DI token, as my methods in class are static amd in code below, this.ngbDateParserFormatter comes undefined. Although this entire code works fine when used inside component as this.ngbDateParserFormatter is not null there. Even if i defined it outside as Static it's still undefined. So, how to inject this token in a utility class.

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct, NgbModal, NgbDate } from 
'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';


export class DateFormatHelper {

 static datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');


  constructor(private ngbDateParserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter) {
 }

 static formatedDate(val: any): any {
 const bDate = val;
  return this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(bDate);
 }

 static parsengbDate(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
 let returnVal: NgbDateStruct;

  if (!value) {
   returnVal = null;
  } else {
       try {
       const dateParts = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'MM-dd- 
        yyyy').split('-');
       returnVal = { year: Number(dateParts[2]), month: 
       Number(dateParts[0]), day: Number(dateParts[1]) };
     } catch (e) {
       returnVal = null;
     }
   }
    return returnVal;
  }
```

Comment: can you share an example of how did  you manage to inject native ISO parser/formatter into your component code?? (as you said it works for you?) I can only "inject" the abstract NgbDateParserFormatter, which does not do anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NgbDateParserFormatter will never be injected because injections only works with classes that are instantiated by Angulars dependency injection (DI).

To solve your problem I suggest to create an Injectable Service with all the methods you need and then inject it into each component which need its methods.

You can see the tutorial to use them [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), but it would look like this:

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct, NgbModal, NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DateFormatHelper {
  private datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
  constructor(private ngbDateParserFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter) {
  }

 public formatedDate(val: any): any {
 const bDate = val;
  return this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(bDate);
 }

 public parsengbDate(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
  let returnVal: NgbDateStruct;

  if (!value) {
   returnVal = null;
  } else {
     try {
       const dateParts = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'MM-dd- 
        yyyy').split('-');
       returnVal = { year: Number(dateParts[2]), month: 
       Number(dateParts[0]), day: Number(dateParts[1]) };
     } catch (e) {
       returnVal = null;
     }
   }
    return returnVal;
  }
}
```

P.S. Remember to add `NgbDateParserFormatter` as provider into your module to inject them (not DateFormatHelper cause I've already registered it in the `@Injectable` metadata).
To understand how injection work take a look [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Comment: If this answer is the one you were looking for please check it as the correct one. If you found another way around to solve your problem could you try to explain it? I need to improve my angular skill too ;) Thank you

Comment: @Fred- I did marked it answered but stackoverflow prompted 'Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'