# how to inject native implementation of NgbDateParserFormatter?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ng-bootstrap

Here ([how to inject ng-bootstrap NgbDateParserFormatter in a utility class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463203/how-to-inject-ng-bootstrap-ngbdateparserformatter-in-a-utility-class)) a similar question has already been asked, however it refers to injection into *static* class, where injection does not work at all.

I can't even inject native (internal) implementation of this class into an Angular component!

so if I declare it as follows:

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
...
})
export class RequestHistoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
  constructor(
...
    protected datePickerFormatter: NgbDateParserFormatter
  ) {}
```

and use as follows:

```
    if (model.requestSince) {
      const requestSinceValue: string = this.datePickerFormatter.format(model.requestSince);
      this.logService.log(`RequestSince value: ${requestSinceValue}`);
      res = { requestSince: requestSinceValue, ...res }
    }
```

so, no exceptions or errors occur, but the code in question produces this:

> RequestSince value: function (value) {\n            if (value != null) {\n                set$1(this, unit, value);\n                hooks.updateOffset(this, keepTime);\n                return this;\n            } else {\n                return get(this, unit);\n            }\n        }--"

this looks to me as if instead of actually calling the `format` method, it somehow.. just prints the code?

Ng-bootstrap documentation never explicitly says anything about whether is this implementation injectable/usable outside of the module: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model

So.. I am entirely at loss here..

EDIT: maybe I don't even need to inject this object, I just want to be able to parse to and from NdbDateStruct and ISO format, so basically in the template code I need to be able to produce the selected date exactly as it's presented in the UI (and vice versa)

EDIT2: I've brought the original implementation code for `NgbDateISOParserFormatter` into my project and nothing has changed. So apparently this has nothing to do with injection but instead what happens is whenever a function returns a template literal with interpolation, it does not return an interpolated literal, but rather a text of a function that is supposed to execute the interpolation. If anything, this is EVEN MORE frustrating to me..

Comment: your model.requestSince must be an object with month,year and day., e.g. `{year:2020,month:9:day:1}`. It's looks like that it is a function, check when you give it value

Comment: model is

```
export interface FilteringModel {
  containsId?: string,
  requestSince?: NgbDateStruct,
  requestTill?: NgbDateStruct
}

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8pmmrc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (using @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": 7.0.0)

```
  constructor(protected dateParser: NgbDateParserFormatter){}
  ngOnInit()
  {
    of({
       containsId:"1,2,3",
       requestSince:{year:2020,month:1,day:16},
       requestTill: {year:2020,month:1,day:16}
    }).subscribe(res=>{
      this.data=this.dateParser.format(res.requestSince)
    })
  }
```

give you data="2020/01/16"

This is the reason because I think your error is in another place

Comment: the problem is indeed rather due to TypeScript magic.... thanks for your answer!